# javascript regex for matching the first alphabet after the newline character

Tags: javascript, regex

'I need only the "r" which appears after the newline character,and not every occurences of "r" '

```
for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++)
 {
 var n= str_array[i].match(/r/g);    //to match every r in the str_array
 alert(n);
 }
```

Comment: After the newline character, or at the start of a line?  Very different.

Answer (score 2):

Use the multiline mode and the `^` anchor, which here means "start of line":

```
 /^r/gm
```

Example:

```
> text = "foo\nroo\nbar\nraar"
"foo
roo
bar
raar"
> text.replace(/^r/gm, "@")
"foo
@oo
bar
@aar"
```